# Запуск окна проекта из другого проекта wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 2 проекта, оба на wpf, оба на .Net Framework 4.8, вопрос в том как мне из одного проекта открыть главное окно другого желательно с присвоением owner, дело в том что если я пишу так:

```
bool isWindowOpen = false;

foreach (Window w in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (w is ChunkCollector.MainWindow)
    {
        isWindowOpen = true;
        w.Activate();
    }
}

if (!isWindowOpen)
{
    Window FilterTypWindow = new ChunkCollector.MainWindow()
    {
        Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow
    };
    FilterTypWindow.Show();
}
```

то получаю исключение **"невозможно указать себя в свойстве Owner"**
Если я использую просто `ShowDialog()` таким образом:

```
MainWindow1 ChunkCollectorWindow = new MainWindow1();
ChunkCollectorWindow.ShowDialog();
```

то при закрытии окна `ChunkCollectorWindow` закрывается и главное окно основного проекта. Важен еще и тот факт, что все эти странности происходят после публикации проекта, в дебаге работает все как нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста нормальный способ запуска и закрытия окон при работе с двумя и более проектами.

Comment: `Process.Start(пусть к exe файлу второго проекта)`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, но как мне указать путь до exe в присоединенном проекте?

Comment: собирать проекты в одну папку например и указывать относительно исполняемого файла

Comment: Попробуйте подключится к проекту через зависимости в Visual Studio и уже по туда просто вызвать Window.Show();. Не уверен что это работает, сам ещё не проверял, но сейчас проверю и если что то изменю комментарий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Шаг 1:

### Подключить к главному проекту второй через ссылки

Если они в одном решении, то можно через вкладку "Проекты"
[image: Ссылки-проекты]

Если в разных или же вам не нравится 1, то через .exe файл второго приложения:
[image: Ссылки-обзор]
**Для наглядности я так и сделал.**

## Шаг 2:

### Реализация во 2 приложении

**НЕ УДАЛЯЙТЕ КОНСТРУКТОР БЕЗ АРГУМЕНТОВ!!!**

```
public MainWindow() ///Оставляем обязательно. Если профи, то можешь удалить но с ошибками разбирайся сам
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txt.Text = "Ничего не было, запущено напрямую";
}

public MainWindow(string a) ///пример передачи аргумента
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txt.Text = "Сообщение от окна 1: " + a;
}
```

### Реализация в 1 приложении

Просто подключаем пространство имён второго приложения, либо используем напрямую (как я)

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new WpfApp2.MainWindow("тест123abc").Show(); ///Передаём аргумент
}
```

## Шаг 3

### Запускаем и радуемся что всё работает

[image: итог]

## QA:

#### 1. Это два независимых проекта?

**Да, это два независимых проекта.**

#### 2. Могу ли я передать что хочу второму окну?

**Да, можно. Пример есть в коде.**

#### 3. Что, если проекты на разных платформах(.NET Core, .NET)?

**Пробуйте, но может не работать**

#### 4. А если на другом ЯП?

**Нет.**

#### 5. Нужно ли для этого заранее запускать второй проект? И будет ли он работать с запущенным экземпляром?

**Нет, запускать не надо. Нет, не будет, так как второй проект используется как библиотека. Исполнение идёт от имени первого проекта, но логика не меняется.**

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но в этом проекте решение всплыло в самом неожиданном месте, а именно дело было в хостировании приложения, после того как я убрал хостирование Owner стал присваиваться нормально